# Angular fullstack. Handle orders without public API

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm experimenting with a simple web shop using Angular Fullstack (https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) with the authentication boilerplate.

What is the best way to accomplish this:

- I want to be able to put data (orders) into the MongoDB from a form within a view – not restricted in any way (i.e. without the need of logging in with an account)
- I do not want the orders to be visible through url/api/orders
- I want to be able to view the orders from a view restricted to logged in admins

Should I create an endpoint, and then restrict this in some way? Or can I do this without an endpoint?

It's my first MEAN stack project, thanks in advance.

Comment: So from API point of view: the `PUT` to `url/api/orders` should be open but `GET` should be for authenticated users, as simple as that

Comment: Got it, thanks. Is there some way to read more about how to do this? I'm not sure how to do the actual auth check using the authentication boilerplate. I get the idea, but couldn't get it to work. I guess I should do it in my order controller in the exports.index function (and some others), no? Has the auth boilerplate some "isAuth" that's easy to use?